# Want to add field in group price table in magento 1.9.0.1

Tags: magento-1.9

I need to add new field in group price table (catalog_product_entity_group_price) currently I am in

```
app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/catalog/product/edit/price/group.phtml
```

I have done all related work here but not sure what I need next.
in above mentioned table i have created the field name: percent with same price type.
added field in form

```
+ '<td><input class="<?php echo $_htmlClass; ?> " type="text" name="<?php echo $_htmlName; ?>[{{index}}][percent]" value="{{percent}}" id="group_price_row_{{index}}_percent" onblur="update_percent(group_price_row_{{index}}_price, group_price_row_{{index}}_percent, Pro_Price)"/></td>'
```

plus

```
var groupPriceControl = {
    ......

        <?php if ($_readonly): ?>
        if (arguments.length < 3) {
            return;
        }
        <?php endif; ?>
        var data = {
            website_id: '<?php echo $this->getDefaultWebsite(); ?>',
            group: '<?php echo $this->getDefaultCustomerGroup(); ?>',
            price: '',
            percent: '',
            readOnly: false,           
            index: this.itemsCount++
        };

        if(arguments.length >= 3) {
            data.website_id = arguments[0];
            data.group = arguments[1];
            data.price = arguments[2];
            data.percent = arguments[3];
        }
        if (arguments.length == 5) {
            data.readOnly = arguments[4];
        }

        ........   

        $('group_price_row_' + data.index + '_percent').value    = data.percent;
        ........

};
```

also

```
<?php foreach ($this->getValues() as $_item) : ?>
groupPriceControl.addItem('<?php echo $_item['website_id']; ?>', '<?php echo $_item['cust_group']; ?>', '<?php echo sprintf('%.2f', $_item['price']); ?>', '<?php echo sprintf('%.2f', $_item['percent']); ?>', <?php echo (int)!empty($_item['readonly']); ?>);
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

all other feature working fine and if i give fixed value of percent in above then it show but nothing save any value of percent in database all other working is fine for group price.Please guide someone what i need next show percent value save in database and also i can read from database?
Thanks